# What are some of the more interesting ways you have used memcached?

Tags: memcached

After implementing a `memcached` caching layer into my schema tools I'm wondering if there is more capability to use `memcached` services other than the canonical:

```
rec = cache.get(make_cache_key(k))
if rec: return rec
rec = dbi.execute(query_string(k))
cache.set(make_cache_key(k), rec)
return rec
```

usage of row caching?

Anything like JSON/XML caching of structured data? Graph data? Images?

Answer (score 0):

At that point, redis starts looking far more useful!

http://www.redis.io/